# Docker cant run script executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker

I'm running a small tesseract API using docker. The ruby app calls the command line to use tesseract on an image. Before it does so it uses a script to pre-process the image first:

```
post '/extractText' do
  begin
    bas64Image = Base64.decode64(params[:image])
    imageFile = Tempfile.new(['image', '.jpg'])
    imageFile.write(bas64Image)
    imageFile.close
    `textcleaner #{imageFile.path} #{imageFile.path}`
    output = `tesseract #{imageFile.path} --psm 6 stdout`
    p output
  rescue
    status 402
    return "Error reading image"
  end
  status 200
  return output.to_json
end
```

the app ignores the line `textcleaner #{imageFile.path} #{imageFile.path}` currently as it does nothing.

When testing in command line with something like `docker run tess textcleaner receipt3.jpg receipt3.jpg` i get the following error:

```
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"textcleaner\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"textcleaner\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

FROM tesseractshadow/tesseract4re

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential ruby-full libffi-dev libgmp3-dev ruby-dev

WORKDIR /home/work

RUN gem install bundler

COPY Gemfile .
COPY textcleaner /home/work
RUN chmod +x /home/work/textcleaner

RUN bundle install

COPY . /home/work

EXPOSE 8080

CMD bundle exec ruby app.rb
```

I dont know how to add the file to $PATH. When i do:

```
COPY textcleaner $PATH
RUN chmod +x $PATH/textcleaner
```

I get

```
chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/textcleaner': Not a directory
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x $PATH/textcleaner' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

on the second line.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Docker file you should have this line:

```
ENV PATH /path/to/your/textcleaner:$PATH
```

read more here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: Thanks for replying, when i add `ENV PATH textcleaner:$PATH` 
`RUN chmod +x $PATH/textcleaner` to my Docker file i het this error: chmod: cannot access `'textcleaner:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/textcleaner': Not a directory`

Comment: Your command should look like this: ENV PATH /home/work/:$PATH

Comment: that gives me a similar error: `chmod: cannot access '/home/work/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/textcleaner': No such file or directory`

Comment: You don't have to do COPY textcleaner $PATH RUN chmod +x $PATH/textcleaner